# Unable to run OTRS daemon, OTRS6 on Cent OS 7

Tags: perl, otrs

**I am facing issue while trying to start ORTS daemon on CentOS linux**

FACILITY:

> OTRS-otrs.Daemon.pl - Daemon
>   Kernel::System::Daemon::DaemonModules::SystemConfigurationSyncManager-07

MESSAGE:

> Access denied for user 'otrs'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

When I am trying get the status using command:

```
./opt/otrs/bin/otrs.Daemon.pl status
```

getting this message:

```
Manage the OTRS daemon process.

Daemon running
```

But when I go to the web page it says that OTRS Daemon is not running.
Any help is appreciated!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from the mysql daemon and has nothing to do with Perl.  Try this on the command-line on the server running otrs:

```
mysql --user=otrs --host=localhost --password=XXXXXXX
```

That will probably fail with the same error.  Once you have fixed your mysql configuration so that the command succeeds, otrs should also start.

Omit the option `--password` and let mysql prompt you for the password, if you  are not alone on the machine.

Another reason for the failure could, of course, be that you have misconfigured otrs, and you have to change the mysql user, host, or password.

Answer (score 1):

After searching for solution for two days i finally get it working.
I first change to /opt/otrs/bin/ directory.
To get the daemon working, you have to start the daemon as otrs user. 
To do that just change user to otrs : you can use this command. (su otrs) from your terminal, you will be prompted for the password for otrs. Just enter the password and use the (whoami) command to check if you are otrs. If it shows that the current user is otrs issue this command (./otrs.Daemon.pl status) to see the current status of the daemon. if it shows that the daemon not running then issue this command (./otrs.Daemon.pl start).